# How can I limit a forEach loop to iterate only 16 times

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to limit the forEach loop to only show a maximum of 16 results.  Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
  <div class="events-list" data-bind="if: (typeof(Events) != 'undefined')" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Events">
      <!-- ko if: StatusImage -->
      <div data-bind="foreach: EventNames" style="margin-bottom:-6px;">
        <article data-bind="attr:{class: OfferType== 'TM Event' ? 'TMEvents event-item smooth-hover1' : 'SpecialEvents event-item smooth-hover1'}" style="display:table">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/131x70">



          <div data-bind="attr:{class: OfferType== 'TM Event' ? 'btn-cell TMEvents' : 'btn-cell SpecialEvents'}" class="btn-cell" style="display:table-cell!important;">
            <a style="width:233px; margin-bottom:2px;" target="_blank" data-bind="attr: {href: Ticket, class: OfferType && OfferType=='TM Event' ? 'button buy' : 'button view'}">
              <span data-bind="text: OfferType && OfferType== 'TM Event'  ? 'TICKET/EVENT INFO' : 'VIEW EVENT'"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

Comment: simple just keep condition i.e `<!-- ko if:$index() < 16 --> //your html <!--/ko-->` . cheers

Comment: You might also try a foreach on EventNames.slice(0,16). I don't know whether it will actually work, but it should be easy to try.

Comment: Strangely, when I try         <div data-bind="foreach: Events.slice(0,16)">
It limits it to 10 results...weird.

Comment: @MichaelSpatafore have you tried the above mentioned way which should work fine for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `slice` works:

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: items.slice(0, 16)">
    <li data-bind="text: number + ' '+ name"></li>
 </ul>
```

Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wVrSJUNereGI56W4JrTf?p=preview) showing this.